# C# console app won't send UDP multicast packet on Windows Server 2003

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, windows-server-2003, multicast

I can't seem to get my little test app to send a UDP multicast packet on a particular machine running Windows Server 2003. I have it setup to send a packet to Google's public DNS and another to 239.192.250.250. It runs fine without throwing any errors. But in the Wireshark output, only the Google packet shows up. Any ideas?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    var data = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello world");
    socket.SendTo(data, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("8.8.8.8"), 80));
    socket.SendTo(data, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("239.192.250.250"), 80));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And here's the Wireshark output:

```
No.  Time        Source      Destination      Protocol  Length  Info
205  1.83925300  **********  8.8.8.8          UDP       53      Source port: 62432  Destination port: http
```

On every other machine I've tested including a Windows 2008 R2 server, I get something to the effect of:

```
No.  Time        Source      Destination      Protocol  Length  Info
58   4.52926800  **********  8.8.8.8          UDP       53      Source port: 56530  Destination port: http
60   4.52940400  **********  239.192.250.250  UDP       53      Source port: 56530  Destination port: http
```

Comment: Is the Windows 2003 and 2008 server connected to the same type of router? Because if you are using a switch router, wire shark cannot see all packets from another machine.

Comment: The Windows 2003 and 2008 servers were actually on completely different networks. The 2008 was a Rackspace cloud server and the 2003 was a client's in-house server. I brought it up because I wanted to dismiss the idea that it might be a limitation of Windows Server in general. The test was also done on a Window 7 box in the same client's network, and it worked fine. So as far as I know, I'm just having the problem on his server.

Comment: When I posted the wireshark traffic, I assumed I was seeing the outgoing traffic. Assuming that's the case, is it possible for the router to interfere? Wouldn't wireshark sit between the router and the network interface? Regardless of the network setup, I would still think I should see outgoing traffic to both IP addresses.

Comment: So I just tried send data to a random IP address, and it didn't show up in wireshark like I thought it would. I'm guessing now that I don't understand enough about networking. Does the traffic only show up if it was actually sent somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a [Network switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch), they only routes the packet to the connection of the destination machine.  Whereas an unswitched hub broadcast packets to all ports.

Wireshark does packet sniffing therefore it cannot see all packets on a switched router.

Here is excerpt from [Switch Reference @ Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SwitchReference):

> As noted in the [Wireshark FAQ](http://www.wireshark.org/faq.html#promiscsniff), capturing in a switched network environment can prove to be challenging. An individual switch port will receive broadcast, multicast, and unicast traffic destined for that particular port. In most cases it won't receive unicast traffic for other ports, which is what you're probably trying to capture.